# Return rows from MYSQL table A where table_A.col_1 = table_b.col_2 without using a left outer join?

Tags: mysql, database, join, subquery

In a MySQL database with  two tables  `table_A` and `table_B` I want to return selected row columns from `table_A` based on comparison with values in `table_B`. The below erroneous line sums up the idea:

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, col_3 FROM table_A where table_A.col_1 = table_B.col_2;
```

I do not want any elements from `table_B`.

**Why I can't use a left outer join:** I've tried this with a left outer join as illustrated here(https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) however the database complains that the column names are ambiguous and changing table column names in the database isn't an option.

Comment: Please show the outer join you tried that "isn't an option". And if you don't want columns from tableB, why would you want to left join to it?

Comment: I can't do that here. The code is way to long and reveals too much about the database I'm working on. That's why I've simplified it to the above

Comment: Fine then show a simplfied version. And tell us why if you don't want columns from tableB would you want to left join to it?

Comment: Just look at the linked example in the question.

Comment: I looked and your query is not there. I think you just need to qualify the columns - see my answer...

Comment: Thanks. The erroneous query in my above question isn't taken from the link. The link was to visually illustrate, with accompanying code, what I mean't by left outer join. I didn't want to use a join in my code, but I couldn't remember or find the syntax for getting the same result. I know there's another way of doing it than the accepted answer, but I can't recall it. Senior moment!  But the accepted answer works!

Comment: The "other way" is the other answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you want rows in `table_A` whose  `col1` can be found in `table_B(col_2)`, you can use `exists`:

```
select a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3 
from table_A a 
where exists (select 1 from table_B b where b.col_2 = a.col_1);
```

If you want rows that do not exist in `table_B`, then just change `exists` to `not exists`.

Note that I prefix the column names with the (alias of the) table they belong to. This is called *qualifying* the columns, and is how you avoid the ambiguous column name problem that you seemingly have met when trying to `join`.

Comment: The above works without aliasing the table in the select statement. Though the alias is necessary for the `where exists` part of the statement. This is useful given I'm selecting quite a lot of elements in the table I'm actually working. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If column names are ambiguous, qualify them, eg

```
select table_A.col_1, table_A.col_2, table_A.col_3
from table_A
join table_B on table_A.col_1 = table_B.col_2
```

or for brevity you can assign an aliases to tables:

```
select a.col_1, a.col_2, a.col_3
from table_A a
join table_B b on a.col_1 = b.col_2
```